# How to share state between child component (siblings) in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I would like to pass state to a sibling or even a grandparent whatever.

I have 3 components. Inside `Header`, I have a button with an onClick function to toggle a Dropdown Menu inside `Navigation`. And by the way, I would like to pass the same state to `AnotherComponent`.

How to pass state (such as `isDropdownOpened`) from `Header` to `Navigation` and `AnotherComponent`?

```
<div>
     <Header />
       <Navigation />
        <div>
          <div>
             <div>
               <AnotherComponent />
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lift the state up to common closes ancestor and pass state by props.for example the parent component of `Header, Navigation and AnotherComponent`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the exact reason why ["React Hooks"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) have been developed (and hyped by the community ), **but don't use them yet in production, they are still in early development (alpha) and their specification/implementation might be changed!**

You problem can be solved using the awesome [“React Context“](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API which allows to pass data to components no matter how deep they are nested in the tree.
To get to know to context read the extensive documentation linked above. I'll only explain a small and quick example here:

1. Create a context component and export the consumer

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

// The initial value can be anything, e.g. primitives, object, function,
// components, whatever...
// Note that this is not required, but prevebents errors and can be used as
// fallback value.
const MyContext = React.createContext("anything");

// This component is the so called "consumer" that'll provide the values passed
// to the context component. This is not necessary, but simplifies the usage and
// hides the underlying implementation.
const MyContextConsumer = MyContext.Consumer;

const someData = { title: "Hello World" };

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <MyContext.Provider value={someData}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
);

export { MyContextConsumer };
export default App;
```

2. Import the created consumer in any component and use the provided value

**AnotherComponent.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { MyContextConsumer } from "./App";

const AnotherComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <MyContextConsumer>{({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>}</MyContextConsumer>
  </div>
);

export default AnotherComponent;
```

3. Render the app with both context components

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
import AnotherComponent from "./AnotherComponent";

const Root = () => (
  <App>
    <AnotherComponent />
  </App>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, rootElement);
```

The component will render a level 1 heading with the "Hello World" text.

[image: Edit stackoverflow-53648661-how-to-share-state-between-child-component-siblings-in-reactjs]

Comment: Thanks!!! I prefer this solution, but what would be the solution using Hooks? Can you do that?

Comment: I tried this but It doesn't work... It's not the same tree.

Comment: to < MyContextConsumer> have to always be inside <MyContextProvider> right ?

Comment: I've extended the example code and added a Codesandbox (MVCE).
Yes, the `Consumer` component must always be wrapped by the `Provider` component.

Comment: app and anotherComponent are parent-child not siblings.

Answer (score 8):

You have different approaches to address this situation.

- Keep the state in the top component and pass it to children through props
- Use a state container to keep and share your application state among components (e.g. https://redux.js.org/)
- Use the new [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) feature. Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

Comment: I tried React Context but it doesn't work when It's not the same tree, right?

Comment: Exactly. Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components. If you want a global store, you can consider using Redux.

Answer (score 4):

> How to pass state (such as `isDropdownOpened`) from `Header` to `Navigation` and `AnotherComponent`, please ?

You hold the state in an ancestor of `Header` and pass that state to `Haeader`, `Navigation`, and `AnotherComponent` as props. See [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the documentation.

Example:

```js
const Header = props => (
    <div>
        <span>Header: </span>
        {props.isDropdownOpened ? "Open" : "Closed"}
    </div>
);

const Navigation = props => (
    <div>
        <span>Navigation: </span>
        {props.isDropdownOpened ? "Open" : "Closed"}
    </div>
);

const AnotherComponent = props => (
    <div>
        <span>AnotherComponent: </span>
        {props.isDropdownOpened ? "Open" : "Closed"}
    </div>
);

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isDropdownOpened: false
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(({isDropdownOpened}) => {
                isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;
                return {isDropdownOpened};
            });
        }, 1200);
    }
    render() {
        const {isDropdownOpened} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
              <Header isDropdownOpened={isDropdownOpened} />
              <Navigation isDropdownOpened={isDropdownOpened} />
              <div>
                 <div>
                     <div>
                          <AnotherComponent isDropdownOpened={isDropdownOpened} />
                     </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Wrapper />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

There are some other options, which [Arnaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087711/arnaud-christ) usefully provides in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648741/157247).

Comment: Thanks, lift the state up is kind of complicated no? It's the same way we do form input and form?

Comment: @Steffi - It's one way to ensure a single source of truth for that information. if there's other information you need to hold in the same way, you might make them both properties of an object you share through the tree. See [Arnaud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648741/157247) for more options, though. You're not the first to find this cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Like how TJ Said, use the state of the parent component. That way one state is shared by all the sub components, which is what you wanted I presume.

```
class ExampleParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isDropdownOpened: false
    }
  }

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.setState({
        isDropdownOpened: !isDropdownOpened
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Header open={isDropdownOpened} toggleDropdown={ this.toggleDropdown }/>
          <Navigation open={ isDropdownOpened}/>
          <div>
             <div>
                 <div>
                      <AnotherComponent open={ isDropdownOpened} />
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}


class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={ this.props.toggleDropdown }>TOGGLE ME</button>
                { isDropdownOpened && (
                    <h1> DROPPED </h1>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this part of code: `<button onClick={ this.props.toggleDropdown } />` to `<Header toggleDropdown={ this.toggleDropdown } />` then  `toggleDropdown() {
    this.setState({
        isDropdownOpened: !isDropdownOpened
    });
  }` So the function onclick for toggle come from the parent?

Comment: on clicking the button, it calls the props.toggleDropdown which points to the function that toggles the isDropdownOpened, on change of that the new toggled value is drilled down to all the components that subscribe (?) to that state.

Comment: Yes, the toggle comes from the parent and is propagated to all the child. You can even store the value in the Header component but to send it to the siblings, you'd still have to create a state in the ParentComponent and propagate the value down to the rest of the children. No single source of truth if we do it that way, hence I moved it up to the Parent and propagated it to all the children. But this way is a very opinionated coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `this.state.variableName` to access

```
<ChildComponent data={this.state.name} />
```

And to pass functions

```
<ChildComponent data={this.HandleChange} />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
First Send the data from the first child to the common parent using callback 
function and then send that received data (stored in state in parent component)
to the second child as props.
```

you can also read this article - https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-communicating-between-components