# setting state from a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

First of all, my approach could just be misguided from the start.

I have a component that lists objects added by a sibling component.

I would like the list component to update when a new object is added.

As you can see, I'm calling the same function (getHostedServiceList) in both components. Obviously, this would need t be cleaned up, but I'd like to get it working first

I'm using hooks to accomplish this.

//input

```
const options = [
  { value: '1', label: '1' },
  { value: '2', label: '2' },
  { value: '3', label: '3' },
];

// class Remotes extends Component {
const Remotes = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [service, setService] = useState();
  const [url, setUrl] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState();
  const [apiUrl, setApiUrl] = useState();
  const [services, setServices] = useState();

  let HOME = process.env.HOME || '';
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    HOME = process.env.USERPROFILE || '';
  }

  const getHostedServiceList = () => {
    console.log('props', props);
    if (!fs.existsSync(`${HOME}/providers.json`)) {
      return newMessage(
        `Unable to locate ${HOME}/providers.json`,
        'error',
      );
    }
    const payload = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync(`${HOME}/providers.json`),
    );

    setServices(payload);
  };

  const setProvider = selectedOption => {
    setService(selectedOption.value);
    setUrl(`http://www.${selectedOption.value}.com`);
    setApiUrl(`http://www.${selectedOption.value}.com/api/v1`);
  };

  const { onAddRemote } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Add a remote host:</div>
      <StyledSelect
        value="Select Provider"
        onChange={setProvider}
        options={options}
      />
      {console.log('service', service)}
      <TextInput
        label="Url"
        defaultValue={url}
        onChange={e => {
          setProvider(e.target.value);
        }}
        disabled={!service ? 'disabled' : ''}
      />

      <TextInput
        label="API Url"
        defaultValue={apiUrl}
        onChange={e => setApiUrl(e.target.value)}
        disabled={!service ? 'disabled' : ''}
      />

      <TextInput
        label="Token"
        onChange={e => setToken(e.target.value)}
        disabled={!service ? 'disabled' : ''}
      />

      <TextInput
        label="Display Name"
        onChange={e => setDisplayName(e.target.value)}
        disabled={!service ? 'disabled' : ''}
      />

      <Button
        disabled={!service || !url || !token}
        onClick={() => {
          onAddRemote({ service, url, apiUrl, token, displayName });
          getHostedServiceList();
        }}
      >
        Add Remote
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

//list

```
const HostedProviderList = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [services, setServices] = useState();

  let HOME = process.env.HOME || '';
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    HOME = process.env.USERPROFILE || '';
  }

  const getHostedServiceList = () => {
    console.log('props', props);
    if (!fs.existsSync(`${HOME}/providers.json`)) {
      return newMessage(
        `Unable to locate ${HOME}/providers.json`,
        'error',
      );
    }
    const payload = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync(`${HOME}/providers.json`),
    );

    setServices(payload);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('props 1', services);
    getHostedServiceList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Flexbox>
        <Title>Provider List</Title>
      </Flexbox>
      <div>
        {services &&
          services.map((service, i) => (
            <Service key={i}>
              <ServiceName>{service.displayName}</ServiceName>
              <ServiceProvider>{service.service}</ServiceProvider>
            </Service>
          ))}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I would like the list component to update when a new object is added.

Comment: this questions seems to be answered multiple times. it is about state management in react. you have multiple options like redux, mobx, context...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share state between child component (siblings) in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648661/how-to-share-state-between-child-component-siblings-in-reactjs)

Comment: by the way, I am not sure if you can run your code normally since you are using fs module on browser

Answer (score 0):

This is where something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) comes in handy. These tools allow you to create a "store" - the place where you load and *store* data used by different components throughout your app. You then connect your store to individual components which interact with the data (displaying a list, displaying a create/edit form, etc). Whenever one component modifies the data, all other components will receive the updates automatically.

One way this cross-communication is accomplished is through a [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) mechanism - whenever one component creates or modifies data, it *publishes* (or "dispatches") an event. Other components *subscribe* (or "listen") for these events and *react* (or "re-render") accordingly. I will leave the research and implementation up to the reader as it cannot be quickly summarized in a StackOverflow answer.

You might also try the new [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), as this allows you to easily share data between components. If you choose this option, please take special care to do it properly as it is easy to be lazy and irresponsible.

To get you started, here are some articles to read. I highly recommend reading the first one:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html
- https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react
- https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use Redux (or React's own 'context') for global state handling. However, a simpler solution to be considered might just be to send the data to the parent and pass to the list component like so:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = { objectsAdded: [] }

  onObjectAdded = ( obj ) => {
    // deepclone may be needed
    this.setState({objectsAdded: this.state.objectsAdded.concat(obj)})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ListComponent objects={this.state.objectsAdded} />
        <ObjectAdder onObjectAdded={this.onObjectAdded} />
      </Fragment>
  }
}
```